# How can i create a multi-level dropdown menu containing images preferably using css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

The sample dropdown menu can be seen on [BuzzFeed.](http://www.buzzfeed.com)
The dropdown levels should open up on hover just as in the case shown above.

Comment: Will this help you ? http://javascript-array.com/scripts/simple_drop_down_menu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/as547/3/)** is what you are looking for. There are loads of examples on the internet. You don't need JavaScript or jQuery to do this. Of course it would be possible but you can achieve this with pure CSS.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="parent"><a href="#">Parent1</a></li>
        <li class="parent"><a href="#">Parent2</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="first">
                    <a href="#">Child1</a>
                    <img src="http://marketingland.com/wp-content/ml-loads/2013/04/google-g-logo-2012-100x100.png" alt="img1" title="img1" height="40" width="40" />
                    <p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Child2</a>
                    <img src="http://marketingland.com/wp-content/ml-loads/2013/04/google-g-logo-2012-100x100.png" alt="img1" title="img1" height="40" width="40" />
                    <p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Child3</a>
                    <img src="http://marketingland.com/wp-content/ml-loads/2013/04/google-g-logo-2012-100x100.png" alt="img1" title="img1" height="40" width="40" />
                    <p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="parent"><a href="#">Parent3</a></li>
        <li class="parent"><a href="#">Parent4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#menu ul{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#menu li{
    list-style-type:none;
}

.parent{
    float:left;
    margin-left:20px;
}

#menu a{
    text-decoration:none;
}

#menu ul ul{
    display:none;
    width:300px;
    background:orange;
}

#menu ul li:hover > ul{
    display:block;
}

#menu ul li ul li{
    padding-top:40px;
    display:inline;
}

#menu ul li ul li a{
    float:left;
}

#menu ul li ul li img{
    float:left;
}

.first{
    padding-top:0 !important;
}
```

Comment: What if after I hover on one of the child elements,I want similar another set of child elements to open on the right side,and not at the bottom of each element?

Comment: Do you want the child items next to each other or do you want to add another submenu for the children?

Comment: There was a similar thread to your question. So I found that fiddle and edited it a bit. Is that what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/fD9eF/477/

Comment: I created the first level of dropdown which drops down on hover.But, now when i hover on one of the child elements of the drpdown i want to be able to view a related window with images and text similar to as in BuzzFeed.

Comment: Just as we hover on the Entertainment tab in BuzzFeed a dropdown opens up.Now, when we hover on Celebrity tab a new window opens up in the existing container.Thanks in advance.